# помогите решить задачку на sql

Tags: sql

Необходимо вывести все модели самолетов, на которых был совершен хотя бы один рейс, с указанием количества рейсов, выполненных на каждой модели. Рейс считается выполненным, если самолет прибыл в пункт назначения. Элементы выборки должны быть упорядочены по убыванию числа рейсов.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала покажи таблицу данных(колонки).

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

[image: 30 cbvfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff]
Репозиторий создан для участников SQL-соревнований ИТ школы. С его помощью участники могут протестировать свои SQL запросы на данных, близких к тем, которые используются в тестирующей системе на Степике.

Отладка SQL скриптов
Поднять локальный сервер с MySql. Рекомендуется версия MySQL 5.7.12, так как именно эта версия используется в тестирующей системе Степика
Отредактировать функцию run_queries() в файле local_sql_query_test.py. Не забудьте передать нужные параметры в функцию connect_to_airtrans_db() в соответствии с настройками вашего сервера базы данных. База создается при помощи sql/INIT_DB.sql. В примере запускается скрипт из sql/test.sql
Запустить скрипт в IDE или при помощи python3 local_sql_query_test.py